# Is it possible to do multi-variable logistic regression with varying time series data?

Tags: python, time-series, regression, classification, logistic-regression

I'm an analytics noob so please bear with me! Apologies in advance for the long post.

I'm trying to build a classification model that predicts whether an employee will leave a company (attrited) or not (active) based on data from daily survey questions which are scored on a 5-point scale (1 being most negative & 5 being the most positive). I have average score data by employee_id, month and question in the below format (30 or so questions with one question asked daily)

| month | employee_id | Q1-How satisfied are you with your job? | Q2-Would you recommend working for this company? | ...Q30 | current_employee_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emp_1 | 3.5 | 3.7 | 4.0 | active |
| 2 | emp_1 | 3.7 | 4.1 | 3.2 | active |
| 1 | emp_2 | 2.3 | 2.8 | 3.6 | attrited |
| 2 | emp_2 | 1.8 | 2 | 3.2 | attrited |
| 3 | emp_2 | 1.7 | 2.1 | 3.0 | attrited |
| -- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | emp_200 | 4.1 | 4.3 | 0.0 | active |
| 5 | emp_200 | 3.8 | 4.0 | 3.8 | active |

As employees are constantly joining and leaving, their tenure with the company varies. Some employees could have a long tenure and several months worth of data is available for their scores, others could have a short tenure and only a month or two worth of data might be available for them, probably only for a few questions if they left before some questions were even posed to them. I have employee tenure by number of days as well, if needed.

My end goal is to build a model that would classify employees as active or attrited based on their survey scores, probably also taking their tenure into account.
One logisitc regression model I built in excel was using average scores by employee and question, irrespective of their tenure and classifying them as attrited (1) or active (0). So there was only one row of data per employee_id and the input data set for the model looked something like below.

| employee_id | Q1-How satisfied are you with your job? | Q2-Would you recommend working for this company? | ...Q30 | current_employee_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp_1 | 3.5 | 3.7 | 4.0 | 0 |
| emp_2 | 2.3 | 2.8 | 3.6 | 1 |
| -- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp_200 | 4.1 | 4.3 | 3.9 | 0 |
| emp_201 | 3.8 | 4.0 | 3.8 | 1 |

This model was only 44% precise in predicting attrited employees (1) with a 0.3 probability cutoff. And this only happened after I removed a lot of rows for employees which did not have good score data. One other reason the model output was so bad was also because the mix of active employees is a lot larger than attrited ones in the dataset (80%-20%), so even though the classification accuracy was 84%, the true positive rate for attrition was low (~ 44%)

So I want to see how to improve this model, by taking the employee tenure into account, either as another attribute or doing some sort of time series analysis. I know this model is not scalable in excel at all and would probably need to be built in Python. I have been looking for papers and documentation and haven't found anything yet that fits my use case. Hence, I wanted to open it up to the community to see if there are suggestions or resources.

Apologies again for the long post! I appreciate all the help and will try to provide more information if needed!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this topic would be appropriate on one of these sites? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254090/858527

Comment: Thanks, will post there as well!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to research the following libraries in python:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas
import random 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

Heres some basics though you may not have more EDA to do therefor pyplot may not be needed? Sounds like your feature selection is pretty much done based on your data?

You didn't specify how the data set is looking but I would imagine with some basic interval based variable data you can back fill with a random module.

Also, just because your results are not strong, does not conclude it's not right. It could be an accurate result just not a strong model.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs!, I'll explore sklearn. 
Yes, feature selection is pretty much done. A goal of the this model is also to find out scores of which questions have a higher impact on an employee leaving or staying.

The data set is confidential so I couldn't give a lot of information but I'll explore the random module piece as well.